Process Command Line Field not populating
Recently I encountered that process command line field from some windows servers was not populating on IBM QRadar. So I enabled the process command line field from group policy management. It worked for major servers but for 3 windows servers it did not work. The windows versions for them are 2019 standard. The process command line field unlike others servers are not populating on QRadar. If anyone help me in this case to resolve this issue.
I enabled the process command line field option from Group policy management, Audit success for process creation. Even though I rebooted the servers but still not having those field populated on QRadar. I have worked on 100+ servers for this issue I faced in my environment. It worked fine but for the 3 servers it did not.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
